# Series to power example

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, exponentiation

community.

Found an example which seemingly easy but I cannot get the proper idea.

Consider absolute convergent $\forall z$ series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}$ . Since $z^k$ function can be considered as linearly independent, next problem can be formulated:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{k}z^{k}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}\right)^{N}$

Here $N$ - integer, $\alpha_k$ - unknown. The question is whether there is an easy way to find $\alpha_k$ at least up to some finite $k$? If there is no analytic way, I would like to know at least how to setup this problem on some programming language. I was thinking about multinomial theorem; however, this one isn't much applicable, as fas as I see.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Power_series_raised_to_powers and solve the recurrence for the $a_k$'s instead of the $c_k$'s.

Comment: @Gary thanks a lot, that thing solves.